# Xamarin: How do I pass commandline parameter when debugging?

Tags: xamarin

Using Xamarin 4.2.3(60), I want to debug a .NET app that takes command line args,  I have tried setting the projects General parameters , eg, "/p /Users/Tester/Automation", but when I run in the debugger the  Mina method string[] args is null?  I have also tried setting the "Run With -> Custom Parameters by editing the Default setting the Arguments = "/p  /Users/Tester/Automation" and Working dir to "/Users/Tester/Automation", but when I then "Run with" and choose the saved Custom mode, the program still does not appear to have been passed the arguments?

Anyone know how to  run the debugger and pass command line args to the program being debugged?

Answer (score 5):

You can add command line arguments via the **Parameters** field within **Project Properties** -> **Run** -> **General**.

EG:
[image]

Comment: and how do you use them later in the project?

Comment: They will come through in the `args` string array parameter of the applications `Main` method.